# 'Could not set parameter at position' when update row with NULL value

Tags: java, mysql

I'm having some trouble making this works. I have a table where three fields can be NULL: alumno, fechaInicio and fechaDefensa. I pass the possible null values to another method to check them.

```
public static void actualizarProyecto(int id, String nombre, String descripcion, String alumno, String profesor, String fechaInicio, String fechaDefensa, String convocatoria, int finalizado, int disponible, float nota) {
    consulta = "UPDATE proyectos SET nombre='" + nombre + "', descripcion='" + descripcion + "', alumno='" + alumno + "', profesor='" + profesor + "', fecha_inicio='" + fechaInicio + "',"
            + "fecha_defensa='" + fechaDefensa + "', convocatoria='" + convocatoria + "', "
            + "finalizado=" + finalizado + ", disponible=" + disponible + ", nota='" + nota + "' WHERE id=" + id + "";
    CONEXION.actualizarProyecto(consulta, alumno, fechaInicio, fechaDefensa);
}
```

Because I can't set the values to NULL directly I have this second method that check if the field is null or empty and then set it to null or not.

```
public void actualizarProyecto(String consulta, String alumno, String inicio, String defensa) {
    PreparedStatement state = null;
    try {
        state = conexion.prepareStatement(consulta);
        if (alumno == null) {
            state.setNull(3, Types.VARCHAR);
        } else {
            state.setString(3, alumno);
        }

        if ("".equals(inicio)) {
            state.setNull(4, Types.DATE);
        } else {
            state.setString(4, inicio);
        }

        if ("".equals(defensa)) {
            state.setNull(5, Types.DATE);
        } else {
            state.setString(5, defensa);
        }

        state.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error al insertar el contenido en la BBDD.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

When running the program I get `Could not set parameter at position 3, parameter length is 0`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to set parameter values in a prepared statement, the statement needs to contain a '?' for each parameter you are setting. For example:

```
consulta = "UPDATE proyectos SET nombre=?, descripcion=?, " +
    "alumno=?, profesor=?, fecha_inicio=?, fecha_defensa=?, " +
    "convocatoria=?, finalizado=?, disponible=?, nota=? WHERE id=?";
```

Then, you set the parameters for each '?'.

The added benefit of this approach is that it helps you avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks. I tried after this, but only used '?' on the nullable values.

Comment: If you read up on SQL injection attacks, you'll see why using '?' for all parameters is a good idea.